# Habeo with genitive

Tags: genitive

Sīc scrīpsit [Forcellīni](http://linguax.com/lexica/forc.php?searchedLG=k):

> K Græcorum littera est, non Latinorum, qui ejus loco *c* **habent ejusdem potestatis**.

What is the significance of the genitive case with *habeō*?

I gather that the sentence above means "K is a letter of the Greeks, not the Latins, who in its place **give** *c* **the same meaning**," i.e. *habeō* in its sense of "regard in a certain way". But I thought that that sense of *habeō* took a double accusative. Does the genitive here function like **as** in English "they regard *c* **as** producing the same sound"?

Can you show me a couple attestations of *habeō*, classical or otherwise, that illustrate its usage with the genitive in this way? Or if this meaning of the genitive also works with other verbs, an illustration or two of those?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with habeo=taking part in possessing an abstract, uncountable quality rather than holding/owning sth in exclusivity?

Comment: @Rafael Ah, maybe the genitive here simply denotes possession: _habent_ c _ejusdem potestatis esse._ Or maybe we could even say _Latine_ c _est ejusdem potestatis._

Answer (score 10):

Bearing in mind that letter names are generally indeclinable in Latin, I would parse this slightly differently:

> K Græcorum littera est, non Latinorum, qui ejus loco [litteram] C habent ejusdem potestatis.
> *K is a letter of the Greeks, not of the Latins, who in its place have C, a letter of the same meaning.*

In other words, I would take the *ejusdem potestatis* as an adjunct modifying *[litteram] C*, not another argument of *habent*.

Comment: Novācula Occamī sānē concurrit! Quōmodō Latīnē "Oh, duh, of course" dīcitur?

Comment: I would call that a genitivus qualitatis, which I think is more restricted than an ablativus qualitatis (I thought it had something to do with the ablative being more common when it was adjective + substantive, whereas, the genitive is more common with a mere noun substantive).

Answer (score 1):

This is called the *[genitive of indefinite value](https://classics.osu.edu/Undergraduate-Studies/Latin-Program/Grammar/Cases/genitive-case)*. In these situations the genitive is used when the verb is one of valuing or estimation. Examples of such verbs are: aestimo, duco, habeo and facio.